# How to categorize containers in Unity configuration file

Tags: xml, configuration, unity-container

Is it possible to apply a category attribute to a container tag so that I can later use it to only retrieve certain containers?

I am looking to do something like this in my config file:

```
<container name="Example1" category="ExternalService">
<container name="Example2" category="ExternalService">
<container name="Example3" category="Miscellaneous">
```

Then in code I want to be able to do something like...

```
section.Containers.Where(c => c.category == "ExternalService").ToList();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't. You could use a kind of "namespace" to categorize containers:

```
<container name="ExternalService.Example1">
<container name="ExternalService.Example2">
<container name="Miscellaneous.Example3">
```

and then:

```
section.Containers
       .Where(c => c.category.StartsWith("ExternalService."))
       .ToList();
```

Comment: I believe you're correct as I couldn't find anything anywhere.  Ended up just using a related enum and ensuring that the enum members match the container names.  So I do an Enum.GetNames and only use the containers that have matching names.